# Which square should be cut to minimize loss?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-verification, logic

> From a paper size of $950mm × 1200 mm$, squares with a side of $64 mm$ or $46 mm$ can be cut. Which square should be cut to minimize loss?

My attempts:

We have, for square with side 64 mm, the maximum number of squares that can be cut, is equal  to $278$

> $$950×1200-64^2×278=1312 mm^2$$

For square with side 46 mm, the maximum number of squares that can be cut, is equal  to $538$

> $$950×1200-46^2×538=1592 mm^2$$

Then, we get $1312<1592$

So, the answer must be $64 mm^2$. Is this answer correct? Because, the answer given in the book is $46 mm$. Where is the error in this approach?

Comment: What's "damage"? Where did $278$ and $538$ come from in your calculation?

Comment: How do you arrive in $278$ and $538$, resp.?

Comment: @5xum I fixed the question.

Comment: @Learner What's "loss"?

Comment: @5xum I mean unused area

Comment: Have the squares to be aligned to the edges of the paper or they can by rotated by any angle?

Comment: @Hume2 The text is just what I wrote above.

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to find how many of each square can fit the paper:
$$\frac{1200}{64}=18.75 \to 18; \frac{950}{64}\approx 14.84\to 14\\
\frac{1200}{46}\approx 26.09\to 26, \frac{950}{46}\approx 20.65\to 20$$
Now calculate the waste (i.e. damage):
$$1200\cdot 950-18\cdot 14\cdot 64^2=107,808,\\
1200\cdot 950-26\cdot 20\cdot 46^2=39,680$$
Hence, the squares $46\times 46$ leave less waste.

Note: It is assumed the sides of squares are parallel to the sides of paper.

Comment: (+) Thank you. I think my mistake is I missed it."Note: It is assumed the sides of squares are parallel to the sides of paper." am I right?

Comment: @Learner Intuitively I'd say, rotating the squares would only _increase_ the combined height _and_ width of the squares, hence worsening the fit and increasing paper loss. So I was wondering, what did you have in mind if it wasn't parallel? Maybe a 45 degrees rotation?

Comment: @Ruud Helderman I dont know. Now, I have no idea.

Comment: @Learner For example, a 182x182 sheet gives 5 instead of 4 squares of 64x64 when rotated 45 degrees. But with the given dimensions, parallel alignment appears to be optimal.

Comment: @RuudHelderman You are right..